# Can I use a JS file to render previews when using MarkItUp?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can use a JS file instead of a server side file eg. PHP to render my previews when using [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you could do is add a custom button to the tool bar if you want to be fancy, but for a simple way just add a link below let us say Preview then grap the code and past it to a div holder.  Something like,

```
$('#preview').live('click',function(){
    $('#myDivHolder').html($('.markItUpEditor').val());
});
```

That is pretty much it.  You can get way more fancy, do it on the keydown, put it in the setup file so it's on the toolbar.. tons of ways to skin that cat.. but that little bit of code should get you started.  HTH Cheers -Jeremy